# Are there planes designed for going supersonic in a dive only, not in leveled flight?

Tags: aircraft-design, supersonic, transonic

Are there any sub-/transsonic planes that are able to go supersonic in a dive without damage nor losing control but can't go above Mach 1 in horizontal flight? Some planes can go into leveled supersonic flight on afterburners only, but I mean planes that don't have any.

Comment: Does the space shuttle count?

Comment: Also, Felix Baumgartner is designed to go supersonic in a dive but not in horizontal flight, but he is a person, not an airplane.

Comment: @QuadmasterXLII, designed, or evolved?!  ;)

Comment: Just "able to", or designed intentionally?  (you use both terms, but they aren't as interchangeable as you might think)  There are plenty of planes that could survive going supersonic in a dive, (the EA6B I flew being one of them, limited to subsonic when carrying any external stores...) but "designed" implies a specific mission requirement.

Comment: @MichaelHall I'd go towards designed intentionally, but if a plane can survive going supersonic in a dive it's built so that it can survive it. ;-) B737s for instance cannot go supersonic without damage and/or loss of some control.

Comment: @QuadmasterXLII The Space Shuttle and the Buran went supersonic during ascent too, but they're a more complicated matter.

Comment: @Giovanni, good point.  I’m sure designers consider the probability of an excursion in their design.  B737 - unlikely; a subsonic tactical jet performing defensive combat maneuvers - more likely.

Comment: @MichaelHall The Mig-15 reportedly got supersonic in a dive but control was impaired when flying supersonic, since then the MiG-15 flies no faster than Mach 0.92.

Comment: The V-bomber Handley Page Victor was designed to be a supersonic bomber, however its top speed ended up around 1050 km/h. I have read stories about it reaching supersonic speeds in dives. Not specifically designed to go supersonic in dives, but it did happen.

Comment: @Noddle A service ceiling of 56,000 ft, it seems to have been among the highest-flying sub-/transsonic planes ever.

Comment: [Maybe not designed but achieved](https://www.airspacemag.com/history-of-flight/i-was-there-when-the-dc-8-went-supersonic-27846699/)

Comment: @Dave Yeah I knew the DC-8 story, but I rather mean military jets. SilkAir 185 went supersonic as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilkAir_Flight_185

Comment: @Giovanni One of my favorite planes! HP Victor looks so mean and futuristic in its design. The reason for its odd shape, both the fuselage and the wing, was to ensure that shock waves would appear at the same time on the entirety of the plane during transsonic flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much every early jet comes to mind.
Think the Me262, the F-86, the Mig-17. All could go slightly supersonic in a dive without damage (if not kept up for long, obviously) but not in level flight.

I've heard that some jetliners can go slightly supersonic in a dive without damage. Again, only if they pull out quickly and don't stay in the supersonic regime for more than a few seconds, but I've not seen hard data on that.

I've also heard of a souped up G650 that can go supersonic in a shallow dive and and maintain that once reached in level flight and is actually rated for it with a limit of 10 minutes between inspections (iow, the certification authorities are confident it will not take damage for the first 10 minutes of supersonic flight). But that might be exageration on the part of the person who told me about it (supposedly it's a one off conversion including uprated engines, an extra fuel tank, and stronger structural beams).

I'm sure there are other examples.

Comment: I didn't even know there's still a civilian airplane that can go supersonic (if your source is correct about the G650).

Comment: @Giovanni neither did I and though my source may have misunderstood some details they're not prone to bragging.

Comment: Given the fact that some airliners have gone supersonic during incidents and some recovered, it may well be possible. The G650 and 700 are transsonic already anyway.